# How to upgrade WordPress automatically?

Tags: automatic-updates

How to upgrade WordPress automatically?

What is the standard way to upgrade an entire WordPress installation --- core **or** core and plugins, automatically?

Comment: If you type this exact question into google you get many results telling you how to do this. Have you tried those?

Comment: No because I emphasize core OR core and plugins, which is an emphasize I can't do in the search query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default WordPress automatically updates itself, plugins, and themes.
If your WordPress install doesn't do that then you probably have something that disables this.

You can check your theme for something like this

```php
add_filter('auto_update_plugin', '__return_false');
add_filter('auto_update_theme', '__return_false');
```

And/Or in your wp-config.php

```php
define('AUTOMATIC_UPDATER_DISABLED', true);
define('WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE',        false);
```

If your WordPress is not on a local machine and is on a hosting env, and you can't find anything like the code above, you can try contacting your hosting about this, they might provide additional help.

Comment: I host on shared hosting (Namecheap). I should get ready for fun.

Comment: Do theme creators normally implement no-updates for their theme? It's quite disturbing for me to think they do.

Comment: Depends on the theme. I have a custom theme I created and I disable all automatic updates for it. if it's a paid theme I wont be surprised if they also add automatic updates

Answer (score 0):

One of the advantages of WordPress is that it can be easily upgraded. New versions of WordPress are released regularly, and you can upgrade your WordPress site with just a few clicks.

To upgrade WordPress core automatically, long your wp-config.php file add this line:

```
define( 'WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE', true );
```

To enable automatic updates for WordPress plugins, simply go to the Plugins page and beside each plugin click on the "Enable auto-updates" text. Once you've done that, WordPress will automatically update your plugins whenever a new version is released.

Also, you can use a plugin called: https://wordpress.org/plugins/stops-core-theme-and-plugin-updates/ to manage all updated related settings.

Comment: The way to describe to update the core is not automatic.

Comment: Added in more details.