# Do core themes normally allow automatic upgrades?

Tags: theme-development, upgrade

I understand that in general WordPress core and plugins automatically upgrade themselves, depends on the theme, but is it true for **core** themes?

I am planning to create a website which is basically all core with:

- [Akismet](https://akismet.com/)
- [Elementor](https://elementor.com/)
- [Elementor Header and Footer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/header-footer-elementor/)
- [Contact Form 7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/)
- [WP Rocket](https://wp-rocket.me/)
- [Yoast](https://yoast.com/)

I don't install any themes and I work with the core theme and I just want to ensure that core themes allow automatic upgrades for everything.

In the end I just seek full automation in upgrading.

Comment: TL; DR. WordPress automatically updates core/themes/plugins unless "told" otherwise.
Check this WPSO, https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/410659/how-to-upgrade-wordpress-automatically.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to upgrade WordPress automatically?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/410659/how-to-upgrade-wordpress-automatically)